# How do I quicky compile and run Jenkins from source?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

How can I compile (if changes were made) and run Jenkins from source on localhost **without running any tests**?

Obviously that I read the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+Jenkins) but this doesn't really say how to run it without any tests, only to how to compile the war file.

The funny part is that the doc page even specifies on how to run inside the debugger but that's not what I want.

I just want to write a script that compiles and runs it, ideally even killing it if it was already running (so I can run it multiple times without worrying about being unable to start).

I am on MacOS but I am pretty sure that solution would work on almost any system.

Comment: Do you really want to compile Jenkins yourself ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I already did, and was able to run it but using lots of manual steps (like copying the jenkins.war), I just want one simple command to build and run. Yes, I know that it takes a lot of time (and space) first time.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins used maven as it's build tool, so just add this system parameter

```
mvn -DskipTests=true ...
```

to skip the tests.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that running Jenkins from build needs something long like like

```
mvn clean install -pl war -am -DskipTests && java -jar war/target/jenkins.war
```